# Odoo 14 to 16 Duplicate Views not Upgrading

Tags: odoo, odoo-14, odoo-16

I have a duplicate view in Odoo 16 for the web.frontend_layout

One marked with the External ID 'web.frontend_layout' is the correct upgraded version.

Another is unmarked with the External ID, and is a stale outdated version.

[image: Image of duplicate views]

If I try and delete the stale version.  I get an error:

The operation cannot be completed: another model requires the record being deleted. If possible, archive it instead.

Model: View (ir.ui.view)
Constraint: ir_ui_view_inherit_id_fkey

If I try and archive it, my site breaks.  How do I get rid of this duplicate view and allow the updated view to take hold?

Comment: `Model: View (ir.ui.view) Constraint: ir_ui_view_inherit_id_fkey` means there are other views inheriting this view, so deletion is not possible because a database constraint. And if archiving is breaking your web page layout some others things has to be done first, to get the upgraded version used. Hopefully someone will answer you this question.